# Issues with scraping a website with paging in python

Tags: python, database

I am experiencing issues with scraping a website that has paging in it, showing thousands of records that I need to read.
When I scrape the main URL, I get the first 50 results. However, when I add the paging to the URL, the content of the page is returned **without the relevant records** at all, as if adding the paging to the URL is breaking something.

If I take the **exact URL** and put it in the browser, I see the results, and if I view the page source, I see the results as well.

Main URL: **http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/seqDb.php**

URL with paging: **http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/seqDb.php?page=15**

My code below.
What am I missing?

My code:

```
lstCAMP_IDs = []
for i in range(1, 500):
    url = f'http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/seqDb.php?page={i}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    try:
        content = r.content.decode("utf-8")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(i)
    ampAccnPrec = re.findall("(CAMPSQ[0-9]+)", content)
    if ampAccnPrec == None:
        print(i, "error ampAccnPrec")
        ampAccn = ""
        continue
    else:
        lstCAMP_IDs.append(ampAccnPrec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need cookies to traverse pages, so the best way to scrape it is to create a session. And, you need to start at page 0, not 1.

Here's the updated code

```
import re
import requests

session = requests.session()
lstCAMP_IDs = []
for i in range(0, 500):
    url = f'http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/seqDb.php?page={i}'
    r = session.get(url)
    
    try:
        content = r.content.decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(i)

    ampAccnPrec = re.findall("CAMPSQ[0-9]+", content)
    if ampAccnPrec == None:
        print(i, "error ampAccnPrec")
        ampAccn = ""
        continue
    else:
        lstCAMP_IDs.append(ampAccnPrec)
        print(lstCAMP_IDs)
```

Got these sequences from the first page, which is page 0.

```
[['CAMPSQ12088', 'CAMPSQ12088', 'CAMPSQ12089', 'CAMPSQ12089', 'CAMPSQ12090', 'CAMPSQ12090', 'CAMPSQ12091', 'CAMPSQ12091', 'CAMPSQ12092', 'CAMPSQ12092', 'CAMPSQ12093', 'CAMPSQ12093', 'CAMPSQ12094', 'CAMPSQ12094', 'CAMPSQ12095', 'CAMPSQ12095', 'CAMPSQ12096', 'CAMPSQ12096', 'CAMPSQ12097', 'CAMPSQ12097', 'CAMPSQ12098', 'CAMPSQ12098', 'CAMPSQ12099', 'CAMPSQ12099', 'CAMPSQ12100', 'CAMPSQ12100', 'CAMPSQ12101', 'CAMPSQ12101', 'CAMPSQ12102', 'CAMPSQ12102', 'CAMPSQ12103', 'CAMPSQ12103', 'CAMPSQ12104', 'CAMPSQ12104', 'CAMPSQ12105', 'CAMPSQ12105', 'CAMPSQ12106', 'CAMPSQ12106', 'CAMPSQ12107', 'CAMPSQ12107', 'CAMPSQ12108', 'CAMPSQ12108', 'CAMPSQ12345', 'CAMPSQ12345', 'CAMPSQ12346', 'CAMPSQ12346', 'CAMPSQ12347', 'CAMPSQ12347', 'CAMPSQ12348', 'CAMPSQ12348']]
```